# How to make a clear messages command in cog

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Purge(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def clear(ctx, amount = 5):
        if amount == 0:
            await ctx.send("AMOUNT CANNOT BE 0!")
        else:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Purge(client))
```

when i type the command -clear it doesn't do anything nor is there a error message telling me anything

Comment: Consider putting a `print` statement in your `clear` function and then trying again. If you see the printed statement, then you know there's something wrong with your `clear` function. If you don't see it, then there's something wrong with the way your bot is configured, *not* the `clear` function itself

Comment: Not sure, but I think you need 'self' before ctx as the first argument of a function

Comment: oh thank you @EcksDee i completely forgotten that cogs needed a self argument

Answer (score 0):

```
async def setup(client):

   await client.add_cog(Purge(client))
```

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. While your solution may work, answers should also provide some explanation of why the code will resolve the issue raised in the question.